# Choosing the correct subsequence of events s.t. sum of probabilities of events diverge

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Here is the problem.

[image]

I tried choosing $B_n = A_{mn}$ since it is an independent sequence for $m \geq 2$, but I am not quite sure how to guarantee that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_{mn}) = \infty$.

Is it true? If so, why? If not, what other subsequence can you suggest?

This is from [Rosenthal](http://www.drchristiansalas.org.uk/MathsandPhysics/Measure/AFirstLookAtRigorousProbabilityTheory.pdf), btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** It is not generally true that $\sum P(A_{nm})=+\infty$. But it must be true for one of the $m$ following sequences:
\begin{equation*}
(B^{i}_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(A_{nm+i})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, \quad i=0,1..,m-1
\end{equation*}

Comment: With $m=2$. $ $

Comment: Sergio, @Did, I am not quite sure I follow. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_{2n+1})$ is just as bad as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_{2n})$ right?

Comment: Oh but one of those 2 necessarily diverges. THANKS!!!

Comment: @DId Why does m have to be 2? This can extend to 3, 4, etc I think...